# Set path to created folder?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, pdf

I created a folder named PDF in my windows form C# application where I put many pdf-files. I'm using the Adobe PDF reader COM Component and I want to set the path to the current created folder(PDF).

I'm using the full path of the file it works:

> "C:/Users/USER/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/PERFEC1.1/PERFEC1.1/PDF/RedactionCV.pdf"

But it doesn't work on other machines. How do I fix that?

Here is my code:

```
private void btnRedactioncv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(File_Path);
    this.axAcroPDF1.src = File_path;
    this.axAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(false);
    this.axAcroPDF1.setView("FitH");
    this.axAcroPDF1.setLayoutMode("SinglePage");
    this.axAcroPDF1.Show();
}
```

Comment: Please show the code where you save your files

Comment: It's legal to use relative paths in C#.

Comment: thank you but it shows no error i just cant see the file if i trie to use a relative path something like this "~\\PDF\\RedactionCV.pdf" it doesnt work I guess I don't know the exact syntax of it so I cant fetch the file :(

Comment: Does your catch block really contain only throw?

Comment: What do you want the folder path to be related to? the executable directory?

Comment: yes to the folder i created in my app

Answer (score 0):

When you save your PDF, you should use a code like this

```
string pathToSave = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolders.MyDocuments);
pathToSave = Path.Combine(pathToSave, "PERFEC1.1", "PDF");
Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToSave);
string fileToSave = Path.Combine(pathToSave, "RedactionCV.pdf");
... code to save the file ....
```

Now, when you need to retrieve the document, it is easy to rebuild a path that exists on the machine of a different user

```
string pathToLoad = Path.Combine(pathToSave, "PERFEC1.1", "PDF");
string fileToLoad = Path.Combine(pathToLoad, "RedactionCV.pdf");
... code to load file ....
```

The key point of this approach is to use the [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) enum that helps to retrieve well known locations on the end user machine and not to have a hard path stored in your application

Comment: thnx im trying this but im realy a beginner so excuse my question but where do i write the code to save/load the file ? #steve

Comment: I don't know how do you _put many PDF files_ in your folder, neither how do your create that folder. Just supposed that your application is doing that. In any case. The MyDocuments special folder is a symbol that represent the root of the current user Documents folder. If you create/put your files in a path relative to this root folder then you can retrieve them using the mentioned approach that transform the MyDocuments in a real path and then combine the subfolders to retrieve the files.

Comment: i simply added a folder named pdf and copied the file into i think that was stupid

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths are specified like `"subfolder1\\subfolder2\\file.pdf"`, if you want to take a step up use `...`: `"...\\curentfolder\\subfolder1\\subfolder2\\file.pdf"` (this doesn't make sense, but you can use another folder instead of curentfolder). So, in your case it should be `"PDF\\RedactionCV.pdf"`. You can use relative paths to read and write in the same way as you would do with absolute paths. If you're creating a new file make sure the path already exists, because it won't create new folders for you (you can use `DirectoryInfo` for this).